# PHP Downloaded file doesn't work, but file on server is correct

Tags: php

I am really close on this, but I can't quite get this last part to work.

I am trying to set up a web page to compile GBA game code for my students, some of their computers didn't like the compilers so I figured this would be the easiest way to set it up.

I have the compiling all done, and the file it creates works, I pulled it straight from the server to check it, but when it downloads through the browser it isn't working.

```
    $file_url = 'directory/main.gba';
    if(file_exists($file_url)){
            header('Content-Type: application/download');
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_url).'"');
            readfile($file_url);
    }
```

I am not a PHP coder so I don't really know where to go from here, any advice would be appreciated!

PS: I did a diff on the files as well to confirm they are different

Edit: Just tested to see if it was actually seeing the file, when I changed it to a non-existent directory it did not download anything, so it is definitely seeing the file and trying to download it, but something is wrong with the file once it finishing downloading

Edit 2: Seen in comment: I used a hex editor to look at the broken file and it had the text that I echoed prepended to it. Is there a way I can avoid this?

Comment: Is the downloaded file the expected size?

Comment: It's a little bigger, the one directly from the server is 3.46 KB and the one downloaded it 3.66 KB

Comment: Try `application/octet-stream` instead of `application/download`

Comment: That is what I had initially, just tried it again and it has the same problem

Comment: Have you tried comparing the files, to see where they differ?

Comment: I used diff to confirm that they were different, let me find a tool to do a deeper diff

Comment: try to read that file using a curl request with the verbose flag, like `curl http://your_url/script.php -v`, you might get an error message in the header communication that might help

Comment: It looks like the file prepended the text that I echoed in the php script and that's what is causing it. Is there a way to get it to ignore the echoed text?

Comment: I should also say that I am echoing the output from the command line execs I am running, so if it succeeds in compiling they just get a file, if it fails it shows them the output. Can I possibly show the output and download the file without them interfering?

Comment: Instead of echo you can use `fwrite(STDERR, "...")`

Comment: That worked! It didn't show the output, so I also saved it all in a variable and echoed it if it failed to find the .gba file.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!